# where to call delete for the program that never ends implicitly?

Tags: c++, sockets, memory-leaks

I have dynamically allocated memory using new operator for object.

```
classname *p_obj=new classname[5];
```

My program has infinite loop through which it sends and receives data in socket.

i am just using that dynamically allocated object inside the infinite loop.

```
while(1)
{
// Send and recv implementation
// used p_obj here
}
```

Obviously my program will never ends implicitly i have to explicitly do it.

In such situation where to call delete to free the memory hold by p_obj.

I believe we cannot place inside the destructor.

Comment: All the memory will be released to the OS when you kill the program.  A better design would be to use some sort of IPC or other mechanism to signal to the app to shut down.

Comment: This is all pretty circumstantial. Do you modify the object? If so, delete what it's pointing to first. If you don't modify it during your loop, then just don't worry about it.

Comment: @MrDuk No i dont modify it.

Comment: How do you exit the loop when you want to quit? The correct answer will depend heavily on how you do it.